# How to pull a specific data from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a problem that I have to make 10 loops depends on arrays number in order to get the data.

I fixed that by some help from my other post, but I have one issue renaming

The array I'm using

```
Array
(
    [catalog] => Array
        (
            [book] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [took] => Array
                                (
                                    [dodo] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ahmadz] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [lolo] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [tata] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [author] => ahmadz
                                                                    [title] => Midnight Rain
                                                                    [genre] => Fantasy
                                                                    [price] => 5.95
                                                                    [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                                                                    [description] => A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
                              an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
                              of the world.
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [took] => Array
                                (
                                    [dodo] => Array
                                        (
                                            [ahmadz] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [lolo] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [tata2] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [author] => Ralls, Kim
                                                                    [title] => Midnight Rain
                                                                    [genre] => Fantasy
                                                                    [price] => 5.95
                                                                    [publish_date] => 2000-12-16
                                                                    [description] => A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
                              an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
                              of the world.
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

And this how I get a specific data from it

```
$author_array = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $key) {
    if (in_array($key, array("author"))) {
       echo  $author_array[] = $value;
    }
});
```

The problem I have that before these values

```
 [author] => ahmadz
 [title] => Midnight Rain
 [genre] => Fantasy
 [price] => 5.95
```

I have  different keys

tata  and tata2

I want to get only the values  in "tata"  key

but the code above is returning both values from  "tata" and "tata2" keys

Please help me to get the data from one key  not both

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a sloppy method, but it should work. Simply look for the tata key and then extract the author field from that.

```
$author_array = array();
array_walk_recursive($array, function($value, $key) {
   if (in_array($key, array("tata"))) {
      echo  $author_array[] = $value["author"];
   }
});
```

Comment: What does a var dump of $value give you in the above?

Answer (score 0):

simply use nested foreach loop

foreach($array["catalog"]["book"] as $key => $value){foreach($value["took"]["dodo"]["ahmadz"]["lolo"] as $key2 => $value2){echo "author : ". $value2["author"];}}

Comment: it output is  author : jac1author : jack2author : jack3author : jack4   is want values that has tata key as parent I don't want to get all values

Comment: foreach($array["catalog"]["book"] as $key => $value){foreach($value["took"]["dodo"]["ahmadz"]["lolo"] as $key2 => $value2){i f($key2 == "tata"){echo "author : ". $value2["author"];}}}